# Removing sub component from React component?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a component that with this json:

```
{
      "id": 138,
      "created_at": "2016-08-29T08:20:28+02:00",
      "updated_at": "2016-08-29T08:20:28+02:00",
      "title": "Some title.",
      "description": "",
      "employee": {
        "id": 500,
        "name": "Name,
        "title": "Code Monkey,
        "geo_code": "UK",
        "image": ""
      },
      "assigned_employee": {
        "id": 34,
        "name": "Nicolai",
        "title": "Developer",
        "geo_code": "uk",
        "image": ""
      },
      "status": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Pending",
        "color": "#FAFAFA"
      },
      "priority": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Low",
        "color": "#F56954",
        "rank": 0
      },
      "taskables": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "created_at": "2016-08-22T17:07:33+02:00",
          "type": "partner",
          "partner": {
            "id": 652,
            "created_at": "2012-07-31T09:43:43+02:00",
            "name": "Beierholm",
            "geo_code": "UK",
            "city": "London",
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "created_at": "2016-08-22T17:09:07+02:00",
          "type": "lead",
          "lead": {
            "id": 21211,
            "created_at": "2016-08-16T13:08:21+02:00",
            "name": "LeadName",
            "geo_code": "UK",
            "city": "London",
          }
        }
      ]
    },
```

I have an event to be able to remove the taskables from the DOM (parent component), inside the reducers I have this when I map the current items in the state. But the element is not being removed.

```
if(task.id === action.task_id){
    if(task.taskables.length > 0) {
        task.taskables.filter(function(taskable){
            return taskable.id !== action.taskable_id;
        })
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns a new array.

You coded:

```
    if(task.taskables.length > 0) {
        task.taskables.filter(function(taskable){
        return taskable.id !== action.taskable_id;
    })
```

This appears to be throwing the new array away -  don't you need to return it, or something similar?

Just to be clear: your call to `task.taskables.filter()` does *nothing*.

It does not mutate the `task.taskables` array.  It returns a result which you are not using.

Comment: The issue with that one is that removed the entire component instead of removing the child only, also when the *taskable* is null it will fail

Comment: Maybe.  I don't see how we can tell without seeing more code.  But just to be clear: it appars the code quoted in my answer appears to me to do basically nothing.   It calls a function on an array that does not change the array itself, and it throws the result away.

Comment: Just checking if you understood the point I was making in my answer.  I have tried to clarify better.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like below so that it can remove the item without assigning a new array,

```
if(task.id === action.task_id){
  if(task.taskables.length > 0) {
    return { taskables: task.taskables.filter(taskable =>
      taskable.id !== action.taskable_id
    )}
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure he's going to be able to return just a subset of the state from his reducer?